# Circuit with both current and voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am preparing for an upcoming exam. Can someone explain the procedure to solve this kind of problems in detail, please?
[image]

Comment: please explain what you understand and what you do not understand about the circuit ... edit the explanation into your question

Comment: Current source, R1, and voltage source, share the same nodes. This makes it easy to calculate Vs, and I1. The current through R2,R3 can also be immediately found since that branch also shares the same node as the voltage source. Then you know all currents except Is. Use KCL for that.

Comment: I understand the basics like parallel and series. But how do I calculate all those currents and voltages?

Comment: What is the voltage across R1? After finding that, what is the current through R1? Similarly what is the voltage across R2-R3 branch? After finding that, what is the current through That branch? After finding that calculate the voltage across R3 since the current is known.

Comment: @AJN I know that voltage across parallel devices is the same. Is that applicable here with R1? Is voltage across R1 24 volts (as the source with 24 volts) is in parallel with the resistor R1?

Comment: "*I know that voltage across parallel devices is the same*". So the voltage across R1 is 24V as you said. From that, you know the current across R1. Since you also know the voltage across the series association of R2 and R3, you now know all currents.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me out. Now I see it was a very easy problem :D

Comment: [Superposition](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/suppos.html) is another nice tool to simplify a problem like this…although this particular problem is already simple.